# How do <context:include-filter> and <context:exclude-filter> work in Spring?

Tags: spring, configuration

I have several services:

- *example.MailService*
- *example.LDAPService*
- *example.SQLService*
- *example.WebService*
- *example.ExcelService*

annotated with `@Service` annotation. How can I exclude all services except one?

For example I want to use only *MailService*. I use the following configuration:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="example">
    <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="example..MailService*" />
    <context:exclude-filter type="aspectj" expression="example..*Service*" />
</context:component-scan>
```

but now all services are excluded.

Why all services are excluded if exists one rule to include *MailService*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Include filters are applied after exclude filters, so you have to combine both  expressions into one exclude filter. AspectJ expressions allow it (`&` is replaced by `&amp;` due to XML syntax):

```
<context:exclude-filter type="aspectj" 
    expression="example..*Service* &amp;&amp; !example..MailService*" />
```

This is a regex, so your expression ".*Service" means 'any number of any character followed by "Service"'. This explicitly excludes the MailService you want to include.

Comment: what do you mean "Include filters are applied after exclude filters" ? that exclude filter is interpreted first and include filter then allows those types despite they are defined in the exclude filter ? That totally doesn't work for me

Comment: @lisak: In more clear words: include filter can't include types excluded by the exclude filter.

Comment: would you be please so kind and look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4584509/306488 ? It makes me crazy...

Answer (score 34):

Another way to perform this registration is with a single inclusion filter.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="example" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="example..MailService*" />
</context:component-scan>
```

The "use-default-filters" attribute must be set to "false" in this case to keep Spring from adding a default filter equivalent to

```
<context:include-filter type="annotation" 
                        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component"/>
```

Comment: +1 - setting `use-default-filters="false"` is key to preventing scan of other components in the same base-package.  Also works great with regex.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you want to use filter type "regex".  Here's an example from the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters):

```
<beans>

   <context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
      <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*Stub.*Repository"/>
      <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                              expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
   </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

Comment: If you want to include just one Type in the component scan the regex filter type is the easiest way to do that.