# How do I exclude all @Component classes except for one under @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have the following annotation in my code:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={MyClass.class},
            excludeFilters={@Filter(Component.class)}, //@Component
            includeFilters={@Filter(type=ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes=MyClass.class)}
        )
```

`MyClass` is annotated with `@Component` but still want to include it during component scan. However, component scan filters seem to use and logic instead of or. How do I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: add `use-default-filters=false` and only the include.

Comment: +1 @M.Deinum. For detailed discuss see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710444/how-does-work-contextinclude-filter-and-contextexclude-filter-from-spring-3-0

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it. Also mention that there's `useDefaultFilters` attribute under `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: This is a dumb question but if you're only including a single class, why use `@ComponentScan` at all?

Comment: @MilošMilivojević because it's not actually just one class from one package. It's just a cross-section of the actual problem.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. Sorry, had to ask :)

Comment: @MilošMilivojević That's ok. No need for apologies.

Answer (score 2):

`@Configuration` is more deterministic than `@ComponentScan` at all cases.

Rather than workarounding the `@ComponentScan` annotation. You should try to explicitly list your `MyClass.class` in a `@Configuration` class as a `@Bean`, like:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyClassConfiguraiton {

    @Bean
    public MyClass myClass() {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Then `@Import` the configuration class explicitly instead of the `@ComponentScan` annotation:

```java
@Import(MyClassConfiguratrion.class)
```

Or import it via component scan mechanism (since `@Configuration` is meta-annotated with `@Component`).